# Using static variables in Salesforce Apex

Tags: variables, static, salesforce, apex

We've noticed some interesting behavior in our test classes when using static variables to make sure triggers only fire once. Consider the following trigger, class, and testclass:

Trigger:

```
trigger RecursiveTrigger on Account (before insert) {

    if(RecursiveClass.RunOnce) {
        RecursiveClass.RunOnce = false;
        if(Trigger.isInsert) {
            RecursiveClass.doStuffOnInsert();
        }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
            RecursiveClass.doStuffOnUpdate();
        }        
    }    
}
```

Class:

```
public class RecursiveClass {
    public static boolean RunOnce = true;

    public static void doStuffOnInsert() {}
    public static void doStuffOnUpdate() {}
}
```

Testclass:

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class TestRecursiveClass {

    static testMethod void testAccountInsertUpdate() {
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Testing Recursive');
        insert a;
        a.Name = 'Testing Update';
        update a;
    }
}
```

Based of of this I would expect 100% code coverage but when you run this the line RecursiveClass.doStuffOnUpdate(); in the trigger will not execute because the static variable still seems to be set. From what I've read in the documentation static variables are only saved throughout a transaction (i.e. an Insert or an Update). Wouldn't the update in the test class be a whole new transaction or am I misunderstanding this?

The only way I've been able to get around this is by splitting the static variables between one for insert and one for update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the two DML statements `insert`
 and `update` are part of the same Apex transaction and the following excerpt explains it well.

> A static variable is static only within the scope of the Apex transaction. It’s not static across the server or the entire organization. The value of a static variable persists within the context of a single transaction and is reset across transaction boundaries. For example, if an Apex DML request causes a trigger to fire multiple times, the static variables persist across these trigger invocations.

You can find a detailed example about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm).

**Edit:**

One more thing, you need to update your trigger to handle `update` as well like

```
trigger RecursiveTrigger on Account(before insert, before update) {
}
```

**Edit:**

And, here is how you can reach 100% coverage

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class TestRecursiveClass {

    static testMethod void testAccountInsertUpdate() {
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Testing Recursive');
        insert a;
        RecursiveClass.RunOnce = true;
        a.Name = 'Testing Update';
        update a;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is there a way to make separate transactions in a test class? If we're working with test methods that are self sufficient (SeeAllData=false) I would like to insert some Accounts rather then querying the database and updating those.

Comment: That update was in my real code but forgot it in my example :) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: RecursiveClass.RunOnce = true; don't execute until Trigger is running. There is no need in while(Trigger.isExecuting);

Comment: @Chiz Thanks for the insight. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your test should look like

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class TestRecursiveClass {

static testMethod void testAccountInsertUpdate() {
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Testing Recursive');
    insert a;
    a.Name = 'Testing Update';
    RecursiveClass.RunOnce = true;
    update a;
}
}
```

Setting your static variable to true before next DML gives you the idea of next action from user. Static variables are used to prevent trigger loops. Like, you updated an object, then in a trigger you did some manipulations and then update this object. This may cause infinite loop of trigger update. To prevent this static variables are used.